# What is the best way to use the react splitting technique on the code listed below

Tags: javascript

Can i please get some suggestions to use the react splitting technique on the code listed below.

i am trying to solve some errors from sonarlint if i can get some suggestions or references on how to use the react splitting techniques i really appreciate it.

```
import { validEmail } from '.';

export default (fieldName, rules, value, type, required) => {
    const frontError = [];
    if ('match' in rules && value !== rules.match) {
        frontError.push(`Does not match`);
      }

      if (required && (!value || (!value.length && !value.value))) {
        frontError.push(`Please provide ${startCase(fieldName)}`);
      } else if (rules.min && value.length < rules.min) {
        frontError.push(`Please provide a longer ${startCase(fieldName)} - minimum length is ${rules.min}`);
      }

      if (rules.lower && !/[a-z]/.test(value)) {
        frontError.push(`Must contain 1 or more lowercase letter`);
      }

      if (rules.upper && !/[A-Z]/.test(value)) {
        frontError.push(`Must contain 1 or more uppercase letter`);
      }

      if (rules.digit && !/\d/.test(value)) {
        frontError.push(`Must contain 1 or more digit`);
      }

      if (rules.special && !/[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/.test(value)) {
        frontError.push(`Must contain 1 or more special character`);
      }

      if (type === 'email' && !validEmail(value)) {
        frontError.push(`Please enter a valid email`);
      }

      if (frontError.length) {
          return frontError.join(' ');
      }

      return '';
};
```

Comment: Are you sure code splitting is what you want to do here? React's code splitting seems irrelevant to the above block of code, which isn't even a react component. What is the sonar lint error?

Comment: why is it not a react component ? yes code spitting is what i want to do , sonar lint error is reducing the cognitive complexity

Answer (score 0):

- React code splitting is a way to “lazy-load” components as they are needed by the user, which can improve performance of the app
- Cognitive complexity is a measure of how easy a function is to read for developers

Now we've cleared that up, forget code splitting your function  The thing to do is refactor your function to reduce the code complexity, which can be done in a few ways, for example using less shorthand and breaking off `if` statements to separate functions. *It's important to remember that this lint check will favour readability over conciseness.*

It's really up to you how to make the function more "readable", but here's an example:

```js
const startCase = (string)=>
 string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);

const requiredError = (value, required, fieldName) => {
    if (required && (!value || (!value.length && !value.value))) {
        return `Please provide ${startCase(fieldName)}`
    }
    return null;
}

const matchError = (value, match) => {
    if (match && value !== match) {
        return 'Does not match';
    }
    return null;
}

const minError = (value, min, required, fieldName) => {
    if (!requiredError(value, required, fieldName) && min && value.length < min) {
        return `Please provide a longer ${startCase(fieldName)} - minimum length is ${min}`;
    }
    return null;
}

const upperError = (value, upper) => {
    if (upper && !/[A-Z]/.test(value)){
        return `Must contain 1 or more uppercase letter`
    }
    return null;
}

const validate = (fieldName, rules, value, type, required) => {
    const frontError = [
        matchError(value, rules.match),
        requiredError(value, required, fieldName),
        minError(value, rules.min, required, fieldName),
        upperError(value, rules.upper),
        // ...and so on
    ];
    
    return frontError.filter(error=> error !== null).join(' ');
};

const test = validate('Name', {
  min: 3, required: true, upper: true },'ok', 'text', true);

console.log('errors:', test);
```

I recommend using a VSCode plugin such as [CodeMetrics](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kisstkondoros.vscode-codemetrics) that ranks the complexity of a function in real time.